# React Native debugger unable to communicate properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a problem linking my react native debugger to the running application. Somehow, it is being separated in to two, debugger from xcode and debugger from 'react-native run-...'.

Example:

If I run my app using xcode, it creates/launch a debugger and they are both linking just fine. I can see all my updates/changes.

But, when run the app using 'react-native run-ios' or 'run-android', it does not open any debugger automatically so I have to manually run the bugger in my terminal 'react-native start'. This way some packages does not work.

I can not seem to find the reason why the debugger does not launch automatically when running 'react-native run-ios'.

I also can not find the reason why some libraries fail to work when running debugger via terminal.

Please help thanks.

---

Also in addition, when I build the app using xcode and then at the same time run 'react-native run-ios' on the terminal utilizing the existing debugger created by xcode. The simulator that launches from the terminal does not behave the same way as the simulator launches from xcode. Freaking weird

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was able to fixed it . . It has something to do with the scheme. The xcode scheme selected does not match to the one I have inside ios folder . . ios/project.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/project.xcscheme

It turns out, the selected scheme your xcode must match to your project.xcscheme . . case sensitive